# BIOS doesn't detect USB and CD/DVD drive

Tags: linux, usb, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a [Lenovo B460e](http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User%27s%20guides%20and%20manuals/B460e/Lenovo%20B460e%20User%20Guide%20V1.0%28English%29.pdf) laptop. The BIOS does not detect and boot a Linux LiveCD in the optical drive. A Linux LiveUSB does not work either. They are detected from within Windows so there is not hardware damage.

What could be the problem? How can I get my computer to boot from the LiveCD?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? What is not detected; the cd ?

Comment: As I may have misinterpreted the OP's question [please see the original question](http://superuser.com/posts/640210/revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Which Linux LiveCD distro is it?
- Did you burn it to a CD-R as an ISO image or data? (Needs to be burned as an image to be bootable)
- How did you clone the image to the USB thumbdrive? (Needs to be *hybridized* and copied "raw" such as with `dd`)
- What is the boot priority/order in the BIOS? (<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS)
- Have you tried this LiveCD/LiveUSB on another machine?

I have a guide for [burning a livecd in Windows](http://justbrowsing.info/start/#cd_win6)

Comment: what liveusb sir?

Comment: Feel free to revert your question if I misinterpreted it. You mentioned it wouldn't boot from usb, I only assumed you mean a "liveusb". Perhaps you meant a usb harddrive?

Comment: But not detected in BIOS ...

Comment: then how to solve this problem sir?

Comment: @JayaGopi - The question is not clear.